# Login and Registration MySql Issuse

Tags: php, authentication, phpmyadmin, registration

I'm having a few problems with my login php and SQL

This is the error that is showing;

```
Warning: mysql_real_escape_string(): Access denied for user ''@'web83.local.one.com' (using password: NO) in /customers/2/2/3/srbportal.com/httpd.www/core/functions/general.php on line 3 Warning: mysql_real_escape_string(): A link to the server could not be established in /customers/2/2/3/srbportal.com/httpd.www/core/functions/general.php on line 3 Warning: mysql_query(): Access denied for user ''@'web83.local.one.com' (using password: NO) in /customers/2/2/3/srbportal.com/httpd.www/core/functions/users.php on line 4 Warning: mysql_query(): A link to the server could not be established in /customers/2/2/3/srbportal.com/httpd.www/core/functions/users.php on line 4 Warning: mysql_result() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /customers/2/2/3/srbportal.com/httpd.www/core/functions/users.php on line 4
```

General.php:

```
<?php
function sanitize($data) {
    return htmlentities(strip_tags(mysql_real_escape_string($data)));
}
?>
```

users.php

```
<?php
function user_exists($username) {
    $username = sanitize($username);
    return (mysql_result(mysqli_query("SELECT COUNT(`user_id`) FROM `users` WHERE `username` =     '$username'"), 0) == 1) ? true : false;
}

function user_active($username) {
    $username = sanitize($username);
    return (mysqli_result(mysqli_query("SELECT COUNT(`user_id`) FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$username' AND active = 1"), 0) == 1) ? true : false;
}

function user_id_from_username($username) {
    $username = sanitize($username);
    return mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT `user_id` FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$username'"), 0, 'user_id');
}

function login($username, $password) {
    $user_id = user_id_from_username($username);

    $username = sanitize($username);
    $password = md5($password);

    return (mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(`user_id`) FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$username' AND `password` = '$password'"), 0) == 1) ? $user_id : false;
}
?>
```

Any help would be amazing!!

Comment: Stop sanitizing input, use parameterized queries instead. And while at it please do not use md5 for passwords, use bcrypt or pbkdf2 instead.

Comment: Did you *read* the error message?  You need to supply valid login credentials when connecting to the database.  It would appear that your connection code (not shown in the question) isn't doing that.

Comment: Using all functions you can think of is _not_ the right way to "sanitize" a string.

Comment: You are mixing mysql_ and mysqli_???

Answer (score 0):

`Access denied for user ''@'web83.local.one.com'`

You are trying to log in without any MySQL user specified.

And try to use PDO, mysql is deprecated

Answer (score 0):

You can use parameterized queries instead of sanitizing inputs.It would be a good practise if you use `bcrypt` instead of `md5`